# install gitk with git 1.8.3.2

Tags: 12.04, git

I seem to be unable to install `gitk`.   Can anyone help me decipher the below:

```
$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.2
$ sudo apt-get install gitk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gitk : Depends: git (< 1:1.7.9.5-.) but 1:1.8.3.2-0ppa1~precise1 is to be installed
 E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably installed a newer version of git manually, because your version of git is too recent for the gitk package that's in the repository.

You can either downgrade git, or manually install a newer version of gitk.

Comment: according to https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/InterfacesFrontendsAndTools#gitk_.28distributed_with_Git.29 `gitk` is distributed with `git` (and no link is provided). However I get the message that `The program gitk is currently not installed`.

Comment: All debian-based distributions have gitk as a separate package, as does ubuntu. I don't know if it is installed if you install git from source and I don't know how you installed git in the first place. But you wouldn't try to install it if it was already on your system, would you?

Comment: Where do you get the message `The program gitk is currently not installed`?

Comment: @Wilf when I type `gitk` in the command line